# Sorting the images at "More Views" on product pages

Tags: magento-1.7, image, sorting, media

I'd like to change the sorting of the images a product has. To achieve this I have typed the order beginning with 0 and up to 6 in the product's image settings. However, even by clearing several caches the new order won't be shown on frontend. A look to the database at the tables `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value` and `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery` shows me that the settings are saved but it seems that Magento doesn't care that changes have been made.

Have I overseen something? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Simply put the media gallery should be taking these values into account.

One good way of checking is to validate that these images are shown in the correct order in the admin section, if so then there is nothing wrong with the core magento side of things.

You could try reverting back to the default theme to see if that changes it or looking into the file `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Attribute_Backend_Media` and check the sql built in the function `loadGallery`

I hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I got similar issue with CE1.7 too. it happened to be that the images were having different order value for different storeviews, end up, if I change the Sort order in default, it has no impact on different Storeviews.

I do not know how to set and unset this, I mean, not properly. (see below)

For now, I found out that you can set a specific storeview for all images of that product, simply by changing one of either `Label`, `Sort Order` or `Exclude` attributes. So, if you have 10 images, for one specific storeview, you change the label of one image, then the sort order will be screwed for that storeview (I mean, it won't follow the default anymore).

To unset this, I went hardcore with direct database fix :

```
DELETE FROM `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value` WHERE 
     `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value`.`store_id` = 1;
```

And do the same for all storeviews (except 0 of course).

The only drawback I got so far is that I can not translate my label for other storeviews...

**But be careful, I do not know if any side effects.**